# Weird Paypal :Authentication failed

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have created curl script to get PAY_KEY from paypal using adaptive payment method.
When i run with REST CLIENT in chrome browser its gives me success response.
But when i go with live server and PHP code it gives me authentication failed.

[MY PHP CODE](http://pastebin.com/0w9CZX2v)
I have hide password and signature wit "X" characters.

I have attached the prof of sucess response in Browser REST CLIENT.

[IMAGE1](http://troll.ws/image/ed990bed#.UxXM785Qzl8)

[IMAGE2](http://troll.ws/image/309db7f0#.UxXM8M5Qzl8)

[IMAGE3](http://troll.ws/image/2fc9dbae#.UxXM8c5Qzl8)

[LIVE LINK](http://iosappsonline.com/tempo2.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use `http_build_query()` over your post `$values`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ,http_build_query($values));
```

Comment: i try but still same issue